# Understanding NumPy split function to extract sub-grid

Tags: python, numpy, split

So I was given a worksheet exercise as follows:

1. Given the following grid of 25 values, extract the central 3 x 3 sub-grid of `9`s from the larger grid using the `split()` function:

   ```
   1 2 3 4 5
   1 9 9 9 5
   1 9 9 9 5
   1 9 9 9 5
   1 2 3 4 5
   ```

And the solution is as follows:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
        [1, 9, 9, 9, 5],
        [1, 9, 9, 9, 5],
        [1, 9, 9, 9, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
x1, x2, x3 = np.split(x, [1, 4]) 
y1, y2, y3 = np.split(x2, [1, 4], axis = 1)
print(y2)
```

My question is, why is it [1, 4] in the brackets? does this refer to the element number, if so, should it not be [1, 3]?

Sorry if this seems like a very simple question - am still super new to coding!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html). In python, array and list slice ranges are inclusive for the start index and exclusive for the stop index. So indices 1 to 4 means 1, 2, 3.

Comment: According to the docs example - `X1=x[:1]; x2=x[1:4]; x3=x[4:]`.  split doesn't do anything you can't just as well with a list of slices

Answer (score 0):

```
In [755]: x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
     ...:         [1, 9, 9, 9, 5],
     ...:         [1, 9, 9, 9, 5],
     ...:         [1, 9, 9, 9, 5],
     ...:         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

If all you need is one block, just slice directly:

```
In [756]: x[1:4,1:4]
Out[756]: 
array([[9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```